# Как сформулировать?

Tags: грамотная-речь, оформление-текста

Приводится текст:

> ...и не приведете клевету, измышляя его между руками и ногами,...

измышляя его между руками и ногами это дословный перевод с арабского. Это значит что женщина забеременев(ведь чрево образно между двух рук и двух ног) от когото клевещет мужу что это его ребенок.

как это сформулировать?

например если человек испугался, то говорят "душа в пятки ушла"

Comment: Ситуация, сами приведенная, совершенно непонятна. *...и не приведете клевету, измышляя его между руками и ногами,...* - напишите это по-русски. я не понимаю, что значит измышляя "между руками и ногами". "Душа в пятки ушла" - идиома, её значение понятно (страх, испух, неожиданность). А что такое "измышляя его"? Да еще между руками и ногами?!

Comment: Если Вам что-то нужно перевести, давайте всю фразу - пословный перевод. Конечный смысл данной фразы непонятен, нужно всё предложение

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Это не может быть "дословным переводом", При переводе (любом) грамматика не должна нарушаться. А в русском нет управления *"измышляя (кого?) между руками и ногами". И еще, "клевету" не измышляют. Измышлять=придумывать. А клевету только *возводят* или *распускают/, она уже придумана.

Скорее всего "возводить клевету" вам и подойдёт. 
Подходящей идиомы для "между руками и ногами" в русском я не знаю.

А вообще, подумал, тут и слово "клевета" неудачно. Просто обман. Клевета - порочит честь кого-либо, а тут неприменимо.

Answer (score 0):

И не вызывайте сплетни, думая о его объятиях.